# Change Elasticsearch mapping for aws kibana

Tags: amazon-web-services, kibana-4, amazon-elasticsearch

I have setup integration with CloudWatch logs using a subscription. However, I noticed some aspects of the mapping need to be adjusted (for example the 'url' coming through in my web server logs gets parsed as an analyzed field which it makes it difficult to setup proper analysis in Kibana). What is the best way to adjust this mapping ? How to make a field as non analyzed ?
Please note that i am using AWS cloudwatch logs subscription to kibana. So i do not have logstash configuration to modify the ES mapping for analyzed fields.

Setup :
Cloudwatch logs subscription - ES - kibana

Answer (score 2):

It explains [here](https://gist.github.com/nicolashery/6317643) how to update the settings of an index. You can update a not analyze field like [below](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#custom-field-mappings),

```
{
    "url": {
        "type":     "string",
        "index":    "not_analyzed"
    }
}
```

Unfortunately if this doesn't work you will have to [reindex](https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime) the data under the the new mapping which could be quite tiresome.